# Varrendo JSON ...e repetindo imagens

Tags: jquery, json, array

O que ha de errado com esse codigo?
No primeiro item do catalogo tem 2 imagens, e no segundo item tem 1 imagem (JSON). Mas na pagina quando executo mostra o primeiro item com todas as 3 fotos e no segundo item fica correto(só com a ultima).

O que pode ser?
(Obs. Sou novo na programação, entao peguem leve kkkk) Valeu

```
    catalogo = [
        {
            'nome': 'Polo Masculina Detalhe',
            'tamanhos': 'Disponivel nos tamanhos P, M, G, GG',
            'avista': '39,90',
            'aprazo': '42,90',
            'imgs': [
    
                {
                    'cod': 'COD: 1010',
                    'ft': '<img src="imgs/36.webp">'
                },
                {
                    'cod': 'COD: 1011',
                    'ft': '<img src="imgs/37.webp">'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'nome': 'Polo Masculina Outr',
            'tamanhos': 'Disponivel nos tamanhos P, M, G, GG',
            'avista': '39,90',
            'aprazo': '42,90',
            'imgs': [
                {
                    'cod': '1113',
                    'ft': '<img src="imgs/5.webp">'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    
    
    for (var p = 0; p < catalogo.length; p++) {
    
        var sessao = `
            <section class="sec">
                <div class="detalhes">
                    <h2>${catalogo[p].nome}</h2>
                    <p class="descricao">${catalogo[p].tamanhos}</p>
                    <span class="precoVista">${catalogo[p].avista}</span>
                    <span class="precoPrazo">${catalogo[p].aprazo}</span>
                </div>
            </section>
            `
            
            $('.corpo').append(sessao);
    
        for (var i = 0; i < catalogo[p].imgs.length; i++) {
            var imagem = `
            <div class="item">
            ${catalogo[p].imgs[i].ft}
            <span class="cod">${catalogo[p].imgs[i].cod}</span>
            </div>
            `
            $('.sec').append(imagem)
        }
    }
```

Comment: coloca o html tbm e tenta montar esse exemplo funcionando para ficar mais claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegue resolver isso de uma maneira bem simples, utilizando `seletores avançados` do **jQuery** como o **[eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)**. Ele encontra um elemento no DOM referenciando-se pelo índice do elemento:

```js
let catalogo = [{
    'nome': 'Polo Masculina Detalhe',
    'tamanhos': 'Disponivel nos tamanhos P, M, G, GG',
    'avista': '39,90',
    'aprazo': '42,90',
    'imgs': [

      {
        'cod': 'COD: 1010',
        'ft': `<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300
">`,
      },
      {
        'cod': 'COD: 1011',
        'ft': `<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">`,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'nome': 'Polo Masculina Outr',
    'tamanhos': 'Disponivel nos tamanhos P, M, G, GG',
    'avista': '39,90',
    'aprazo': '42,90',
    'imgs': [{
      'cod': '1113',
      'ft': `<img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300">`
    }]
  }
]

for (var p = 0; p < catalogo.length; p++) {
  var sessao = `
     <section class="sec">
        <div class="detalhes">
           <h2>${catalogo[p].nome}</h2>
           <p class="descricao">${catalogo[p].tamanhos}</p>
           <span class="precoVista">${catalogo[p].avista}</span>
           <span class="precoPrazo">${catalogo[p].aprazo}</span>
        </div>
     </section>
  `
  $('.corpo').append(sessao);

  for (var i = 0; i < catalogo[p].imgs.length; i++) {
    var imagem = `
       <div class="item">
          ${catalogo[p].imgs[i].ft}
          <span class="cod">${catalogo[p].imgs[i].cod}</span>
       </div>
    `
    $(`.sec`).eq(`${p}`).append(imagem)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="corpo"></div>
```

**OBS :** O que está acontecendo no seu código é que ele pega as imagens do JSON só que insere as 3 divs **`.sec`** com a imagens no mesmo elemento, por isso o uso do `eq()`.

Comment: Show cara, muito bom. Valeu